# Jquery server control click event is not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, button

There is server control button on web form, it is inside the updatepanel control.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Save Details" ID="btnSave" Width="130px" 
ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Button>
```

Script is in external file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').click(function () {

        alert('msg');
    });
});
```

All the other scripts are running fine but this one is not firing.

Comment: Did you try `$('#<%= btnSave.ClientID %>')`

Comment: I think you forgot to put `#` inside the selector.

Comment: getting this error; Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%= btnSave.ClientID %>

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `#` from your selector:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').click(function () {
//     ^ add # here
        alert('msg');
    });
});
```

Comment: getting this error; Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%= btnSave.ClientID %>

Comment: Try to use: `$("[id$='btnSave']").click(function() {...});`

Comment: I have just realized that click event is fired only once. If i click the button again then click event doesn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

Well one side you are using `ClientIDMode="Static"` and other side you are trying `<%= btnSave.ClientID %>` .

Using `<%= btnSave.ClientID %>` will get element's rendered ID. and your Button's ID will be the same as you are using `ClientIDMode="Static"`. It should be used only when your control is rendering multiple time on page. and using `<%= btnSave.ClientID %>` puts extra overhead on page and hits the line every time while rendering `HTML`.

So conclusion says. Use `'#btnSave'` as  your element selector and avoid using `<%= btnSave.ClientID %>` if your element is rendering single time on page.

this will work the same.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id$='btnSave']").click(function () {
        alert('msg');
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay i have removed the static property from the button control and jquery click event is not firing.

Comment: Well it must work if your control's ID rendering as 'btnSave'.. As you have removed `ClientID="Static"`. Then please see the updated answer.